# VS2012 Screen Disapears When Starting Debugger

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2012, resharper, visual-studio-debugging

I am having the most bizarre problem with VS2012.  In a certain solution, whenever I start debugging of any kind (Resharper test debugger, regular F5, etc.) the UI disappears entirely, but the devenv.exe process stays around.

What increases the strangeness here is that I think the behavior is being caused by a project loaded by the solution, and removing that project then trying to start debugging in the same session of VS2012 causes the issue to reproduce itself.  However, if I remove the project, then restart VS2012, everything works correctly.  Has anyone else experienced something similar?  Any ideas?

The offending project is a fairly straight-forward MVC4 project.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Update (11-13-13):**  It looks like this is being triggered by an MVC/WebAPI project template with an Oracle connection string in the web.config.  I cannot imagine what would cause this.  I will keep everyone posted as I troubleshoot.

**Update (11-20-13):**  Another coworker of mine ran into this issue, and as it seems to be caused by a conflict between Oracle Tools for Visual Studio and Resharper.  By removing Oracle Tools for Visual Studio he was able to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved!**  This turned out to be an issue with an Oracle 12c client installation crossing wires with a botched Oracle 11g client installation and Resharper.  The issue was resolved by forcibly removing all artifacts of any Oracle installations from my computer, then reinstalling the 12c managed client without Oracle Tools for Visual Studio.